# google-code-prettify xml indention

Tags: google-code-prettify

I have added line breaks in a generated xml doc.

```
<aa>"\n"
<bb>some text etc.</bb>"\n"
</aa>"\n"
```

this should end up as:

```
<aa>
  <bb>some text etc.</bb>
</aa>
```

Is this possible with google-code-prettify - or should I do it myself in the code that generates the xml?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Prettify can style source code, but it does not re-indent or break lines.

It will preserve tags in your code so, so you can indent your code using line-breaks or you can use HTML layout to do that as in

```
<style>
  code.prettyprint { display: block; white-space: pre-wrap }
  div.el {margin-left: 2em}
</style>
<code class="prettyprint">
  <div class=el>&lt;aa&gt;<div class=el>&lt;bb&gt;...&lt;/bb&gt;</div>&lt;/aa&gt;</div>
</code>
```

The `<div class=el>` uses `margin-left` to indent by a certain amount, and the `pre-wrap` causes line to wrap within the indented block.